# Java country code. Make the first character always appear

Tags: java, android, string

I wanna to make a country code text field. When user click text field, there preset a "+" at the first. Also, that "+" cannot be deleted.
How can I make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnFocusChangeListener() to set the visibility of the "+" character and TextWatcher() for delete behavior:

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (edt.length() == 0 && edt.hasFocus()) {
                    edt.setText("+");
                    edt.setSelection(1);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        edt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (edt.getText().length() == 0) {
                        edt.setText("+");
                    }
                } else {
                    if(edt.getText().toString().length() == 1) {
                        edt.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is what I want. But need to add 

    edt.setSelection(1);
to if (hasFocus) {}.
Anyway, you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText and set the hint attribute to "+".

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="+" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click drawable folder in res. Then go to New --> Vector Asset and click Icon button. Search for add and find + image & add it.
[image]

Then in EditText control add this + image as drawableStart.

```
 <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:drawableStart="@drawable/plus" />
```

You can change the size or color of the + in it's xml file (under drawable folder)

Comment: The is great. But the image size is difficult to be controlled. Still a good answer. Thanks!